# Popping out storyboard and moving back to previous viewcontroller (nib)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have one storyboard project which I want to integrate in one existing project having nibs and viewcontroller.

I have pushed storyboard from one of the viewcontroller using:

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

How can I move back from the story board to previous view controller, I have added back button and on press of back button I am executing below code but it is not popping out.

```
 @IBAction func goBack(sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dismiss(animated:)` method.

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```